# iOS: CollectionView Vertical Pagination for loading images

Tags: ios, objective-c, pagination, uicollectionview

I want to apply a pagination on collectionView such that if items are less than equal to 20,the collectionView reloads the data.
I tried and the result is fine for pagination, but there is a jerk when the collectionview reloads while going to the next page. How can I overcome the jerky feeling on pagination?

Comment: Try and rephrase your question so that we can see what you’re after. How do you want to load your images? What is it for? Try and do some research on how you think you would solve it and ask a more specific question after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help you. If any problem you face, feel free to comment here.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

{

    if (![self isLoading]) 
    {

        NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];

        NSMutableArray *rowsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[visiblePaths count]];

        [visiblePaths enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *indexPath, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        [rowsArray addObject:@(indexPath.item)];

    }];

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)

    {

        if (indexPath.row == `yourArray.count`) {

            if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable])

            {

                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



                    //your load more work

                });

            }

            else {

                NSLog(@"No Network available");

            }

            break;

        }

    }

}

else {

    NSLog(@"Loading");

}

}
```

Comment: Hi, this doesnt help the colelciton view reload jerkiness go away. Any other suggestion?